# Как правильно отобразить слайдер при верстке

Tags: html, css, slider, слайдер

Всем доброго времени суток) Подскажите пожалуйста как сверстать данный слайдер. Я с js пока не знакома, как все его правильно отобразить в верстке, что-бы потом, когда-то его оживить?) Или может он не очень сложно делается? 
Или может его можно как-то сделать с помощью Slick slider ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно, используя опцию `centerMode`. Вы бы свою разметку и стили показали.

Comment: @ГеннадийЖуров я же и спрашиваю как правильно сверстать, что-бы потом не было проблем при подключении js.

Comment: Коментарий один блок, фото другой и синхронизируете с помощью опций Slider Syncing в Slick